# return empty string if condition isn't met

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make the request filter option for location or/and sensorType return an empty string if any of them is null.

I'm using a select dropdown to change the values of filter.location and filter.sensorType

Expected output:

1. if filter.location is null but filter.sensorType is not null
   `request = ...farms?sensortype=abc&page=3`
2. if filter.location is not null but filter.sensorType is null
   `request = ...farms?location=abc&page=3`
3. if both are null
   `requests = ...farms?page=3`

My current result:

`...farms?location=abc&undefined&page=3`

```js
const [filter, setFilter] = useState({
  sensorType: null,
  location: null,
});


// API REQUEST
const {
  data
} = await axios.get(
  `http://localhost:8080/api/farms?${
          filter.location && `location=${filter.location}`
        }${filter.sensorType && `&sensorType=${filter.sensorType}`}&page=${page}`
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the ternary conditional operator:

```js
condition ? resultIfTruthy : resultIfFalsy
```

```js
const [filter, setFilter] = useState({
  sensorType: null,
  location: null,
});


// API REQUEST
const {
  data
} = await axios.get(
  `http://localhost:8080/api/farms?${
          filter.location ? `location=${filter.location}` : ''
        }${filter.sensorType ? `&sensorType=${filter.sensorType : ''}`}&page=${page}`
);
```